# UPDATE SQL command in C# using parameters

Tags: c#, sql, windows, winforms, parameters

What am I doing wrong? This is the function I have:

```c#
public void editStaff(int ID, string firstName, string lastName, string DOB, string home, string telephone, string email, int positionID, CheckBox chkBoxPartTime, double pay, string emergencyName, string emergencyTel, string NINO)
{

    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE Staff SET [First name] = @First, [Last name] = @Last, [Date of birth] = @DOB,[Home address] = @Home, [Telephone] = @Tel," +
        $" [Email] = @Email, [positionID] = @Pos, [Part time] = @Part, [Pay an hour] = @Pay, [Emergency name] = @Contact, [Emergency telephone] = @ContactTel, [NINO] = @NINO WHERE staffID = '{ID}'";

    //Using parameters I pass each value to the command. This is a more secure way of implementic this that avoids SQL injections.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", firstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", lastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home", home);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tel", telephone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pos", positionID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Part", chkBoxPartTime.Checked);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pay", pay);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", emergencyName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactTel", emergencyTel);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NINO", NINO);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Staff member successfully editted!");
    conn.Close();
```

The error I get is

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'.

I have checked if every value that has been passed is of the correct variable type using breakpoints so all the data is passed correctly and I can't see where the problem might be. Thanks.

Comment: This way of getting data from a database is very old school.  Consider using a micro-ORM like Dapper (or even Entity Framework Core), which will give you strong typing for your parameters and eliminate all of those magic strings.

Comment: You were _so close_ on avoiding SQL Injection. You're parametrizing all your inputs, except the very last one in your "where"

Comment: The error complains that the variable type doesn't match the column type.

Comment: As part of your debugging, can you remove all of the parameters and re-add them one at a time to determine which one is failing?  Also, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: In the function parameters you have `int ID` but in the SQL you have quotes around it: `staffID = '{ID}'`

Comment: Why are you using string interpolation when everything else is a parameter? This exposes you to SQL injection and type conversion errors. Pass ID as a parameter as well

Comment: AddWithValue is very brittle with parameter types. For example, your DOB parameter is passed as a string but if the db expects a DateTime this could lead to many interpretation errors. The same could happen with boolean fields and with decimal/single/double fields. Use the more precise _Add(name, type).Value = x_ approach

Comment: You don't appear to be stating what  your parameter types are for the command e.g. DOB - is that a date type?

Comment: yes you were right, parametrizing the ID has resolved it for me thanks

Comment: Maybe doing a stored procedure would be a better approach

Comment: @Gab: I don't see anything here that's exotic enough to warrant a stored procedure.

Comment: True. Thanks for that Robert. I guess my program is steering toward that as a default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as some of the commenters pointed out it appears that parametrizing the ID variable seemed to be the solution.

Comment: Parameterizing every variable thing in an SQL is always recommended